# Converting a Kerberos token (Microsoft AD) to SAML or JWT

Tags: active-directory, saml, jwt

I have users with Single-Sign-On against Microsoft AD using Kerberos tickets. I would need to have these tickets to be "converted" to either SAML or JWT. Do you know of such a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Azure Active Directory for this, AAD has a Security Token Service (STS) which does exactly this for you.

https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/

You do need to setup ADFS for single signon, but this is something very useful for other scenarios as well.

Comment: Do "normal" on-premise AD:s also have the STS? We have SSO so that is covered, but I don't think we have ADFS in use (we can still use it, if required by this setup).

Comment: ADFS is an on-premises version of the STS, but it's possible to create your own STS,  (but not recommended).  With the ADFS and claims, the location where your services are running isn't bound to the domain anymore